# How to use grunt stylus to compile each file to the original folder?

Tags: gruntjs, stylus

what i want to do is compile stylus files to the same folder where the stylus file in . 
like

```
files: { 'src/**/*.css':'src/**/*.styl']
```

Even I have try the same config on the documnet https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-stylus

```
options: {
  relativeDest: 'out'
},
files: [{
  src: ['src/components/*/*.styl'],
  ext: '.css'
}]
```

and failed.

anyone can help me ?

Comment: Can you please define what you mean by failed?

Comment: means , not work , generate an undefine file on the root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'src/components',
                src: ['**/*.styl'],
                dest: 'src/components',
                filter: 'isFile',
                ext: '.css'
            }]
```